# Checking for multiple error conditions

Tags: java, if-statement, coding-style, coffeescript

I want to verify multiple conditions for validations. Currently, I have it set up such that in case of an error, each condition returns the error message, and an empty string in the absence of any errors. As a result, my code looks something like this:

```
String error = condition1(argA, argB);
if (!"".equals(error)) {
return error;
}
error = condition2(argC, argD);
```

.
.
.

and so on.

I wanted to know if there's a more elegant way of doing this in Java (or cofeescript)?

Comment: You code does not use exceptions. Please clarify.

Comment: Do `condition1()` and `condition2()` provide different implementation??and are the arguments user defined or from maybe some array??

Comment: @Raedwald, stream of consciousness, I was thinking if I should define and throw exceptions (with error message) instead of a raw error message. I have corrected the question to specify that currently the conditions simply return an error message.

Comment: Is that code example Java? Because line 2 does not look legal.

Comment: @Sello yes conditions have different implementations and use user input as arguments.

Comment: @muistooshort, yes, that was exactly what I was going for :)

Comment: @JesseJ, yep it's Java. It's correct, I'm currently using it in my code and it works fine

Comment: That's a bad idea, you should validate everything in both places. If you insist on validating in only one place then the server is that place.

Answer (score 0):

How about rather than having a lot of if statements you just create one method to check since if seems the check is the same for all conditions like.

```
    public String check(String err)
    {
       if (!"".equals(err))
          {
             return err;
          }

         return err;
     }
```

Now whenever you checking you just call the method

```
    check(condition1(argA,argB));
    and
    check(condition2(argC,argB));
```

The string returned ofcause you know what to do with it.
Hope that helps